# Android Lottie Animated Dynamic Text Sticker on Image and Save to Gallery

Tags: android, gallery, gif, lottie, dynamic-text

Is it possible to add a Lottie Animation as a Dynamic Text Sticker on top of an Image in Android and save that file to the Gallery as a video or gif? The best way would probably be to use FFMpeg, but I don't know how to add the Animated Lottie dynamic text sticker to the FFMpeg command. Can I save it somehow as a Gif to the internal storage first and then use it as a File?